# How to mock the same method multiple times use mockito

Tags: android, kotlin, mockito

I have a method that needs to be called multiple times, and I can return the same result in the test case, I invoke `when` use for loop, but is there more simple way to do this?

```
val ONE_DAY_FORMAT: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")

val tempCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
for (i in (0..15)) {
  `when`(accountingDao.sumOfDay(ONE_DAY_FORMAT.format(tempCalendar.time)))
      .thenReturn(100.0f)
   tempCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1)
}
```

Comment: it's sufficient to mock once, no need for a loop. what are you trying to achieve

Comment: In Java, we do it with two ways: 1. `doReturn(-1). doReturn(1). when(mockedObject). mockedMethod()` OR 2. `when(mockObject. mockedMethod()). thenReturn(-1, 1)`. Both these ways will return `-1` in first call and `1` in second call. Subsequent calls throw. I hope you would be able to translate this to kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when the set-up is more complicated, the `doAnswer` strategy would be used:

```
   Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Float>() {
        @Override
        public Float answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            String argument = (String)invocation.getArgument(0);

            if(supportedDates.contains(argument)){
                return 100.00f;
            }else{                  
                return null;
            }
        }
    }).when(accountingDao.sumOfDay(any(String.class)));
```

So you basically catch the input param and then decide based on its value what should be returned dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Move your "when ..." statement out of your loop:

```
when`(accountingDao.sumOfDay(any()).thenReturn(100.0f)
```

Comment: It works for this case, but I actually want the certain values instead of any.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of mocking the same method, mock the method once and call the verify method by passing the optional Verification mode parameter. For example if you want that some method of your mocked class get called twice, you can make a verify statement like this

```
verify(mockedClass, Mockito.times(2)).someMethod();
```

This will test if `someMethod()` is getting called twice.